# Lock Screen causes screensaver to crash, session freezes

Tags: 11.04, freeze, screensaver

Whenever the screen is locked (either by menu or by switching users), bug buddy show up saying the screensaver has crashed, then the entire session freezes up and can't do anything. It must be killed with ctrl+alt+backspace.

When the screensaver control panel is opened the same error occurs, but it doesn't freeze and I can save it.

```
 System: Linux 2.6.38-8-generic-pae #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 05:17:09 UTC 2011 i686
X Vendor: The X.Org Foundation
X Vendor Release: 11001000
Selinux: No
Accessibility: Disabled
GTK+ Theme: Human
Icon Theme: Humanity
GTK+ Modules: gnomesegvhandler, canberra-gtk-module

Memory status: size: 20008960 vsize: 20008960 resident: 6086656 share: 4497408 rss: 6086656 rss_rlim: 18446744073709551615
CPU usage: start_time: 1304204561 rtime: 1 utime: 1 stime: 0 cutime:0 cstime: 0 timeout: 0 it_real_value: 0 frequency: 100



----------- .xsession-errors ---------------------
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:26986): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
--------------------------------------------------
```

This means that anyone who uses this computer will have to log out before anyone else can log in. This is a serious problem. Setting the screensaver to "blank screen" does not solve the problem.

Comment: I've had this problem, too, except nothing shows up and I have to force a reboot. This happens after a certain amount of time after locking the screen.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).